# Creating ResourceResponse objects for unit tests with Azure DocDB

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, azure-cosmosdb, microsoft-fakes

I am using the Microsoft Fakes unit testing framework for testing some methods that make queries to a DocumentDB database.

The `DocumentClient` class has several methods for making queries to DocDB (such as `CreateDocumentAsync()`) which return a `ResourceResponse<Document>` object wrapped up in a `Task<T>`.

I would like to shim [`CreateDocumentAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentasync.aspx#M:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(System.String,System.Object,Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.RequestOptions,System.Boolean)) for unit testing purposes, however the return type, [`ResourceResponse<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn799209.aspx), doesn't appear to have a public constructor, despite mention of one in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt490589.aspx#M:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ResourceResponse%601.).

An extremely simplified version of what I want to accomplish is here:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task MyTest() {
    using (ShimsContext.Create()) {
        // Arrange
        var docClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri("myUri"), "myKey");
         ShimDocumentClient.AllInstances.CreateDocumentAsyncUriObjectRequestOptionsBoolean =
            (DocumentClient instance, Uri uri, object document, RequestOptions options, bool disableAutomaticGeneration) =>
        {
            ResourceResponse<Document> response = new ResourceResponse<Document>(); // "error: does not contain a constructor that takes zero arguments"
            return response ;
        };

        // Act
        var response = await docClient.CreateDocumentAsync(new Uri("myCollectionUri"), "myDoc");

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

How can I create a custom `ResrouceResponse<Document>` object to return in the shimmed method?

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are using SDK version 1.10?  If not, please download the latest SDK.

Comment: @h0n I am using v1.10 of the SDK. Do you know if there a standard way of solving this problem?

Comment: I tested with v1.10 and there was not issue to new up the ResourceResponse class without passing in any arguments.  One thing you can do is to check your packages.config to ensure the SDK version is 1.10.0.    <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.10.0" targetFramework="net451" />

Comment: @h0n Turns out you were correct. I had different versions of the SDK in different projects in my solution. Ensuring I had v1.10 fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @h0n If you want to write that as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comment. v1.10 of the SDK supports ResourceResponse constructor will no arguments.  The packages.config in the project solution should show the version of DocumentDB SDK the project is using:

Comment: i have the latest version of documentdb in my java project's pom file but i don't have access to the public constructor